# How do I pass value to List<string> property while testing my WCF service?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, list, wcf-client, datacontract, wcftestclient

I am testing a WCF service method which accepts a DC type parameter, some of my DC properties are of type List. How do i pass values to that, I tried strings in "", did not accept, Please refer the attached screenshot.[image]

AdjReason in the attached screenshot is of type List. Hope I am clear with my question.

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you are asking Adarsh. You might want to try and rephrase your question a little. It would be better to add code as well, instead of a screenshot (which isn't showing up for me anyway).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check the image I'v uploaded.

First set length=10 and press enter, then click on arrow infront of *AdjReason* to expand it. Fill up the value in the expanded section.

[image: Check the image]

Hope this helps.